# error to open workspace in eclipse oxygen

Tags: eclipse-oxygen

I want to open my workspace in eclipse oxygen, but after little while shown this error

An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/david/workspace/.metadata/.log.

in the log is shown the next message:

```
!SESSION 2017-09-22 09:30:46.092      -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=es_CL
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -data /home/david/workspace -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

This is a continuation of log file /home/david/workspace/.metadata/.bak_2.log
Created Time: 2017-09-22 15:29:35.162

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-09-22 15:29:35.163
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.mouseMove(HyperlinkManager.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4522)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4107)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did this error appeared after doing something specific ? Did you just downloaded eclipse ? Is it the first time you open it ?

Comment: I had restarted eclipse after gitlab did not respond

Comment: Were you pulling (or any git task) something into you workspace when gitlab stopped responding ?

Comment: i was synchronizing the gitlab task

Comment: Did you install any plugin on eclipse ?

Comment: thank for you help, but I solved this error by deleting the .metadata folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error by deleting the .metadata folder from the workspace folder,
but this action restarted all configuration of workspace

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below link to see the versions compatibility of Eclipse and jdk.
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation

I hope it resolves your problem .

Comment: Kindly either post it as a Comment or expand it by quoting the versions compatibility details from the page, thanks!